# Python code block IDE

Tags: python, ide

What is currently the IDE used to edit python with blocks?

I found http://www.raspblocks.com/

But it seems to be for edit code online. I want to install the IDE in the Raspi.

Thank you.

Comment: Thonny is built-in to Raspbian

Comment: I assume you need more than the current version of Scratch / Node Red. Closest I know is edublocks - it has a PI client but still needs internet access for the editing.  The netlabtoolkit has not been updates since 2016 and I’m not sure Python output was built in.  I’ve not looked deeply into rexygen (as it costs) but I decided to learn Python in the end and for my needs it’s not too big a stumbling block to google answers or shout for help.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I'm trying edu-blocks. The Rpi has internet connection. I have not problem to learn Python, the blocks are just for introduce my son to coding.

Comment: Also, thank you for the Thonny suggestion. Trying it too.